# Fullscreen and Repeat Video with Totem Player

Tags: command-line, video, fullscreen, totem

I want to open a video from command line and I want the video to be opened as fullscreen and be repeated forever.

I searched for fullscreen, and found the `--fullscreen` switch in Totem. However, there's no repeat or loop option.

How can I show a video and repeat itself with Totem or any other simple player from command line?

Like:

`totem --fullscreen --repeat video.mp4`

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: MPlayer can do it :  http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/commandline.html

Comment: I added a feature request for such a command-line option at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/-/issues/611

Answer (score 1):

use VideoLan (vlc)

in terminal type

```
vlc -L -f video.mp4
```