# totem crashes -- mplayer works fine

Tags: command-line, video, crash, totem, mp4

Looking to [play](https://askubuntu.com/q/509743/45156) a video with totem but the screen is non-responsive and shows a force quit button:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ mplayer Downloads/media.mp4 
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing Downloads/media.mp4.
libavformat version 57.71.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f31173955e0]Protocol name not provided, cannot determine if input is local or a network protocol, buffers and access patterns cannot be configured optimally without knowing the protocol
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [H264]  208x180  24bpp  12.500 fps  316.6 kbps (38.7 kbyte/s)
X11 error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.89.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 encoder: Lavf57.56.101
Load subtitles in Downloads/
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [xv] 208x180 => 208x180 Planar YV12 
V:   4.2   0/  0  2%  0%  0.0% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ totem Downloads/media.mp4 

(totem:7944): Totem-WARNING **: Failed to register application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
thufir@dur:~$
```

Firing up totem first, then selecting the video just gives a blank screen.  Seems rather unlikely to be a bug -- nothing plays in totem.  Mplayer works fine.  I can purge and re-install.  Nothing in the `man` page relating to verbose output or debugging which I saw.

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (66).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: Do you use X11 or Wayland session?

Comment: gnome-shell I *think*, so that would be wayland(?).  Not sure.

Comment: gnome supports both X11 and Wayland. However 17.10 by default is using Wayland *(if supported by drivers)*. Try logging out, and choosing a non-wayland session in login screen, and see if the problem persist.